# How to overlay div / box on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, css, html, overlay

I have a link and when user hover mouse over it, it should display a box (div) under the link. The box should overlay whatever is under it. How can I do it using css or javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9V8e/). You can modify from there to suit your needs.

```
<div class="hover">Hover here</div>
<div class="overlay" style="visibility:hidden">
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" alt="google" />
</div>​


$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("div.hover").mouseover(function ()
  {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $("div.overlay").css('visibility','visible');
  });
  $("div.hover").mouseout(function ()
  {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
    $("div.overlay").css('visibility','hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: If I add a div under overlay and want overlay to lay over it, how to do it? Currenlty, I see white space created under hover for overlay to be dsplayed.

Comment: This overlay div doesn't actually overlay. This doesn't solve the problem, "The box should overlay whatever is under it."

Answer (score 11):

You have an absolutely positioned div that is hidden, and a child of the link. Then, when you hover over the link, you should unhide the div. I can't provide full CSS, and I haven't tested this, but that should get you started. You'll have to play around with the positioning and sizes.

```
<a href="#" class="special">Somewhere<div class="desc">This is hidden.</div></a>

a.special { position:relative; }
a.special div.desc { background-color:white; display:none; position:absolute; z-index:100; }
a.special:hover div.desc { display:block; }
```

This would be the pure-CSS way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").mouseover(function(){
   $("a[rel='#petrol']").overlay().load();
});
$("#id").mouseout(function(){
   $("a[rel='#petrol']").overlay().close();
});
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.