# Extend DIV to fill TD without breaking mouseover functionality

Tags: html, css, html-table, onmouseover

Using the CSS-only method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874781/how-to-overlay-div-box-on-mouseover/3874872) I'm working on a div extension/popup on mouseover. It works because the hidden div is child of the div being hovered.

I'd like to make the **Description** part of variable height, and I've been looking for a way to lineup the **Price** divs so they all show at the same height, while the Description part expands down as much as needed (without specifying a min or max height to the Description).

There are many previous questions answered about equal-height divs, about extending divs to fill td's, and about placing divs at the bottom of td's but so far I haven't found any way that would do that while at the same time keeping the parent-child relationship for the hover to work.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/danigot/4uYtB/)

```
body {font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center; }
div.special { position:relative; width:160px; background-color:white; border: solid white ;border-width:1px 1px 0px 1px;top:0px; }
div.special div.desc {  width:160px;background-color:white; display:none; border: solid 0px;position:absolute; z-index:100;left:-1px;}
div.special:hover div.desc { display:block;border: solid grey; border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px;box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;  }
div.special:hover {border: solid grey 1px;border-width:1px 1px 0px 1px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; z-index:100;}
table   {text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}​


<table >
<tr>
<td valign="top" >
    <div class="special">
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialnetworkspro/128/Google-BUZZ.png">
        <br><b>Description</b><br>
        <div >Price</div>
        <div class="desc">
            Detailed Specs
            <br>Other Info
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td valign="top" >
    <div class="special">
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/socialnetworkspro/128/Google-BUZZ.png">
        <br><b>Very Long Description</b><br>
        <div >Price</div>
        <div class="desc">
            Detailed Specs
            <br>Other Info
        </div>
    </div>
</td>    
 </tr>
</table>​
```